# Php webservice inserting data to a database

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services

In my Authentication.php class I hava a code like below;

```
public function prepareTicket($data){
    if(array_key_exists('tickettype', $data))
        $this->tickettype = $data['tickettype'];

    if(array_key_exists('ticketinfo', $data))
        $this->ticketinfo = $data['ticketinfo'];
}

 function createTicket(){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket_test (tickettype, ticketinfo) VALUES ('$this->tickettype','$this->ticketinfo')";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->DB_CONNECTION,$sql);

}

function createTicketControl(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ticket_test` WHERE tickettype = '".$this->tickettype."'AND ticketinfo ='".$this->ticketinfo."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->DB_CONNECTION,$sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
        return true;            
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in the other php file I have a code like this;

```
<?php
include_once 'Authentication.php';
use user\Authentication;

$auth = new Authentication();
$auth->prepareTicket($_POST);
$ticketStatus = $auth->createTicketControl();

if($ticketStatus){
    $json['success'] = 1;
    $json['message'] = 'Destek kaydı oluşturuldu';

}else{
    $json['success'] = 0;
    $json['message'] = 'Error!';
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Now my problem is that whenever I try to insert data to my database it returns 'success' = '0' , 'message' = 'Error' and the data couldnt be inserted on the database.I mean the service is not working properly.Any help is appreciated...

P.S.= I am aware of sql injection threat on this code bu it is for android app so no need to worry about it.

Comment: <sarcasm>Google will be happy to hear that Android does not have to worry about SQL injection code.... In this case: it is running on your server, so nobody will be able to find this looking at your Android program and hack your server.</sarcasm>

Comment: You always should worry about sql injections. I could install your app, get the http request send by the application, then modify the body with weird sql code

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. **WORRY ABOUT SQL INJECTIONS. ALWAYS**.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.I realised that in CreateTicket.php I didint call createTicket function from Authentication.php :/